# How come photons in a laser have the same frequency and length so they are considered the same?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, laser

I was watching a video about lasers and how they work and the thing that I did not understand is about photos that electrons emit. Why these photons are the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A photon is an elementary particle carrying energy $E=h\nu$, where h is the Planck's constant and $\nu$ is the frequency of the classical electromagnetic wave that will be built up from a large ensemble of this frequency photons.

In the lasing quantum mechanical phenomenon the atoms emit the same increment of electromagnetic energy as a photon, by fixed by the set up energy level transitions. Since the energy is the same, the frequency will be the same for all such photons and [they will build up a classical electromagnetic wave.](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html)